# How to make custom response in djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, response, django-serializer

So I like the idea of using class-based views and ModelSerializers but I have an issue with it for my particular use case. Maybe I am not using it as it's intended to be used.

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
        model = CarModel
        fields = ['car_name']


# A car can have build for multiple years
class MakelHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   car = CarSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

   class Meta:
        model = MakeHistoryModel
        fields = ['model_year', 'car']
```

The response is:

```
{
  "car": {
           "car_name": "Fiesta"
   },
   "model_year": "2020"
}
```

My two model classes, CarModel and MakeHistoryModel have ["id", "car_name", "manufacturer"] and ["id", "car_id", "model_year", "country_id"] fields respectively.

What kind of a response I really want is:

```
{
  "car_name": "Fiesta",
  "model_year": "2020"
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to first serializer (CarSerializer).Just this serializer which has SerializerMethodField enough for your output:

```
class MakelHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   car_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
        model = MakeHistoryModel
        fields = ['model_year', 'car_name']

   def get_car_name(self,obj):
       return obj.car.name if obj.car_id else ''
       # I don't know your model so to avoid NoneType error, I added this check
```

Comment: I added this "return obj.car.car_name", it works! So my CarModel  has attributes ["id", "car_name", "manufacturer"]. Appreciate the help! Is this a custom-field? This is the correct [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) for it?

Comment: Yes, SerializerMethodField is a custom field actually.If you look into source code, you can understand better. [Here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py) is the source code drf fields

Comment: So there are multiple MakeHistoryModel for each CarModel, how would I sort it by the "model_year" and only get the most latest entry. For example right now I get:
{
  "car_name": "Fiesta",
  "model_year": "2020"
},
{
  "car_name": "Fiesta",
  "model_year": "2019"
},
{
  "car_name": "Raptor",
  "model_year": "2019"
} 

I just want:

{
  "car_name": "Fiesta",
  "model_year": "2020"
},
{
  "car_name": "Raptor",
  "model_year": "2019"
}

Comment: You must manage it with your queryset that you passed to serializer. There are many alternatives.You can use order and distinct methods like that MakelHistorySerializer.objects.all().order('car_id','model_year').distinct('car_id')

Comment: self.queryset.order_by("-model_year").distinct("car__car_name", "model_year") works for collection request but when I want to filter according to requests params it fails. I am doing, self.queryset.order_by("-model_year").distinct("car__car_name", "model_year").filter(car=CarModel.objects.get(car_name="Fiesta")) -> { "car_name": "Fiesta", "model_year": "2020" }, { "car_name": "Fiesta", "model_year": "2019" } *fiesta is coming from request.query_params* is that right? is it efficient?

Comment: It seems true, what is your error message?And how do you pass your query params to this queryset. Also you can add .select_reletad('car') to your queries. Because it provides single database hit for relational access.I mean when you use obj.car.name inside your serializer, it hits to database for getting car of each makehistory record. But if you use select_related, it takes all related cars to memory and only once hit to database.